# perl matching syntax with mail filter

Tags: perl

We have a part of a mail filter that denies emailing system accounts for security purposes. We recently had a user created that ends in "bin". The bin user is restricted, but the user, lets say l.parrbin, gets flagged via the syntax below:

```
my @sysaccounts = qw(
   root bin daemon adm lp sync shutdown halt mail
   news uucp operator games gopher ftp nobody nscd
   vcsa rpc mailnull smmsp apache pcap ntp dbus
   avahi rpcusder nfsnobody sshd haldaemon xfs defang
   clamav monit mysql decode webmaster mailer-daemon
   nagios
);

foreach $acct(@sysaccounts){
  if ($recip =~ /$acct\@/i){
     md_syslog('info', 'Sysaccount Discard');
     return('REJECT', "We do not accept messages to system accounts ($acct)");
  }
}
```

How would I prevent the above code from returning REJECT if a name ends or starts with a name from the sysaccounts?

Comment: You'll want to escape `$acct` in the regex in case someone has a name with a regex metacharacter.  For example, "foo+bar".  `m{\Q$acct\E\@}i` will do it.  http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quoting-metacharacters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
if ($recip =~ /^$acct\@/i){
#              ^
```

In regex, `^` is an *anchor* meaning *beginning of line* (string here)

Comment: or in this context, beginning of string